# Function declaration to return anything, also void?

Tags: function, swift, return, void

Is there a way to declare a function such that I don't care about return value? For example I have this Array extension:

```
extension Array {
    func forEach(function: (element: T) -> ()) {
        for e in self {
            function(element: e)
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want to do:

```
textFields.forEach{$0.resignFirstResponder()}
```

And I can't because the function is declared to return Void.

This would fix it:

```
textFields.forEach{$0.resignFirstResponder();return}
```

But is there a generic way to declare the function such that I can return any value or Void?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add a second generic parameter with no constraints, and type the function to return it, then any return value would be accepted:

```
extension Array {
    func forEach<U>(function: (Element) -> U) {
        for e in self {
            function(e)
        }
    }
}

func f(i: Int)->Int {
    return i * 2
}

func g(i: Int) -> Double {
    return Double(0.0)
}

func h(i: Int) {
    println("\(i)")
}

let a = [1,2,3]
a.forEach(g)  // U will be an Int
a.forEach(f)  // U will be a Double
a.forEach(h)  // U will be a ()
```

However, I’d strongly suggest you not do this and use `for…in` instead.

The only purpose of running a function on an array but not using the return value is for side-effects.  When writing in a more imperative style and using side-effects and external state (as opposed to a more declarative functional style) it’s much better to use `for…in` as a signal that this is what you’re doing.

There are also unpleasant gotchas involved in constructing your own pseudo-control structures.  For example, think about this:

```
// function that does something side-effecty, but
// if it achieves some goal, exist early
func someFunc(a: [Int]) {
    a.forEach { i -> () in
        // goal achieved early,
        // return from func
        return
    }
    assert(false)
}
```

This is a common practice – cut out of a function early if some goal (or failure) is achieved.  But with the `forEach` structure this is a bit misleading.  It looks like a regular loop, but it’s actually a closure, and the return returns from that closure, ready for `forEach` to call the next one (essentially, it behaves like a `continue` in a regular loop).

Comment: I tried using a type parameter but forgot the `<U>` -- thanks! And yes maybe I switch to using for...in instead. Now it looks more understandable that Apple didn't add forEach.

Answer (score 0):

Use `map()`:

```
let textFields : [UITextField] = [] // or whatever
textFields.map{$0.resignFirstResponder()}
```

This way you don't have to specify the return type, and you don't need to reinvent `map` with your `forEach` extension.

Comment: It does feel strange when one is used to pure languages, but I don't think that is a good enough reason to not do it this way. Compare to Haskell, where one would use `mapM` for the same purpose — the only difference is that it is within a monad (`IO` in this case) but as Swift does not represent the presence of side effects within it's types `map` and `mapM` would be the same. Also I would argue it is clear what the line does, because it reads as `nouns.map{noun.verb()}`. 

If you'd rather still define `forEach` the make it even clearer, you can just define `forEach` to be the same as `map`.